# Time function in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the data of 4000 employees in google sheets along with their shift timings (9 hour long shift) spread across 24 hours. I wish to use a formula to understand the most common timing these employees are available in the office (09:00 to 18:00). My results would be 09:00 to 11:00, 11:00 to 13:00, 13:00 to 15:00, 15:00 to 18:00, 18:00 to 22:00, 22:00 to 09:00.

I could have used this formula to derive to the value:

```
=IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A2)>=TIMEVALUE("09:00"), TIMEVALUE(A2)<=TIMEVALUE("11:00")), "09:00 to 11:00", 
 IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A2)>=TIMEVALUE("11:00"), TIMEVALUE(A2)<=TIMEVALUE("13:00")), "11:00 to 13:00", 
 IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A2)>=TIMEVALUE("13:00"), TIMEVALUE(A2)<=TIMEVALUE("15:00")), "13:00 to 15:00", 
 IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A2)>=TIMEVALUE("15:00"), TIMEVALUE(A2)<=TIMEVALUE("18:00")), "15:00 to 18:00", 
 IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A2)>=TIMEVALUE("18:00"), TIMEVALUE(A2)<=TIMEVALUE("22:00")), "18:00 to 22:00", "22:00 to 09:00")))))
```

but the problem is the timings are not in the time format but they are in text format

Comment: Share few sample data as text table then show your desired output. You must research to solve problem by yourself. If you fail then come with your faulty formula so that we can correct. You may also share a sample googl-sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

Suppose Column A has clock ins, and Column B has clock outs. Let Column D have Times starting at 00:00 and going up to 33:00 (8am next day) in 5 minute (or 30, 60 etc) increments.

Let column E be the amount of clock in and outs that an employee was in the office at the time referred to in E.

We will define E to be `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9999,"<="&D2,$B$2:$B$9999,">="&D2)`.

Next, apply some conditional formatting to highlight the most busy times.

Note that you will need *only* the times of day, which it sounds like you have, but you will need to convert overnight shifts to not wrap around midnight.